# Package libc6 is not installed

Tags: linux

I have build LFS 8.0 and prepared a base linux system. I am installing package manager on that system. I have installed dpkg from a source package in it. After installing dpkg when i try to install any .deb package it throws an error along with the list of several dependencies. Among them also their are some dependencies related to gcc and glibc. Althought they are already installed in my LFS system. Have searched alot regarding this but could not find any helping material that why the package could not find its pre-req package even its already installed.

For example when i try to install zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-5_amd64.deb in lfs system, below mentioned error appears:

```
{
root [ /sources ]# dpkg -i zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-5_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package zlib1g:amd64.
(Reading database ... 348 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack zlib1g_1.2.8.dfsg-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zlib1g:amd64 (1:1.2.8.dfsg-5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zlib1g:amd64:
zlib1g:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
Package libc6 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package zlib1g:amd64 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
zlib1g:amd64

}
```

Note: I have installed only dpkg. apt-get is not installed.

Any helping material regarding this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though those libraries may be present on your system, they are not installed as *deb* packages and for *dpkg* they are missing. If you want to use *dpkg*, you will have to install all of those libraries as *deb*s.

Comment: As i have a lfs environment, so to install packages using dpkg, what i have to do so that dpkg recognize the installed libraries and does not give any error regarding installed libraries.?

Comment: I don't know. As a workaround, you can create dummy *libc6* package with no files.